# How to use match with regular expressions in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, matching

I am starting to learn Scala and want to use regular expressions to match a character from a string so I can populate a mutable map of characters and their value (String values, numbers etc)  and then print the result.

I have looked at several answers on SO and gone over the Scala Docs but can't seem to get this right. I have a short Lexer class that currently looks like this:

```
class Lexer {

    private val tokens: mutable.Map[String, Any] = collection.mutable.Map()

    private def checkCharacter(char: Character): Unit = {
        val Operator = "[-+*/^%=()]".r
        val Digit = "[\\d]".r
        val Other = "[^\\d][^-+*/^%=()]".r
        char.toString match {
            case Operator(c) => tokens(c) = "Operator"
            case Digit(c) => tokens(c) = Integer.parseInt(c)
            case Other(c) => tokens(c) = "Other" // Temp value, write function for this
        }
    }

    def lex(input: String): Unit = {
        val inputArray = input.toArray
        for (s <- inputArray)
            checkCharacter(s)
        for((key, value) <- tokens)
            println(key + ": " + value)
    }
}
```

I'm pretty confused by the sort of strange method syntax, Operator(c), that I have seen being used to handle the value to match and am also unsure if this is the correct way to use regex in Scala. I think what I want this code to do is clear, I'd really appreciate some help understanding this. If more info is needed I will supply what I can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This official doc has lot's of examples: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/util/matching/Regex.html. What might be confusing is the type of the regular expression and its use in pattern matching...

You can construct a regex from any string by using `.r`:

```
scala> val regex = "(something)".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = (something)
```

Your `regex` becomes an object that has a few useful methods to be able to find matching groups like `findAllIn`.

In Scala it's idiomatic to use pattern matching for safe extraction of values, thus `Regex` class also has `unapplySeq` method to support pattern matching. This makes it an [extractor object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html). You can use it directly (not common):

```
scala> regex.unapplySeq("something")
res1: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(something))
```

or you can let Scala compiler call it for you when you do pattern matching:

```
scala> "something" match {
     |    case regex(x) => x
     |    case _ => ???
     | }
res2: String = something
```

You might ask why exactly this return type on `unapply/unapplySeq`. The doc explains it very well:

> The return type of an unapply should be chosen as follows:
>
> ```
> If it is just a test, return a Boolean. For instance case even().
> If it returns a single sub-value of type T, return an Option[T].
> If you want to return several sub-values T1,...,Tn, group them in an optional tuple Option[(T1,...,Tn)].
> ```
>
> Sometimes, the number of values to extract isn’t fixed and we would
>   like to return an arbitrary number of values, depending on the input.
>   For this use case, you can define extractors with an unapplySeq method
>   which returns an Option[Seq[T]]. Common examples of these patterns
>   include deconstructing a List using case List(x, y, z) => and
>   decomposing a String using a regular expression Regex, such as case
>   r(name, remainingFields @ _*) =>

In short your regex might match one or more groups, thus you need to return a list/seq. It has to be wrapped in an `Option` to comply with extractor contract.

The way you are using regex is correct, I would just map your function over the input array to avoid creating mutable maps. Perhaps something like this:

```
class Lexer {

    private def getCharacterType(char: Character): Any = {
        val Operator = "([-+*/^%=()])".r
        val Digit = "([\\d])".r
        //val Other = "[^\\d][^-+*/^%=()]".r
        char.toString match {
            case Operator(c) => "Operator"
            case Digit(c) => Integer.parseInt(c)
            case _ => "Other" // Temp value, write function for this
        }
    }

    def lex(input: String): Unit = {
        val inputArray = input.toArray
        val tokens = inputArray.map(x => x -> getCharacterType(x))
        for((key, value) <- tokens)
            println(key + ": " + value)
    }
}

scala> val l = new Lexer()
l: Lexer = Lexer@60f662bd

scala> l.lex("a-1")
a: Other
-: Operator
1: 1
```

Comment: If you are looking for more efficient and probably simpler parsing of grammar, then perhaps parser combinators would be a better way to go.